# ExpandableList example

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I need to use ExpandableList in my app. I found this example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html which I could compile without any problem.

But from this example, I'd like to do 2 things that I can't achieve:

1) Integrate this custom expandable list as a part of a layout and not the only element of the layout as it is now.

2) Use XML layouts for the generic view and for the child view.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you explain a little bit more? with code sample of what you trying to do, would be better.

Comment: 1) The provided example returns an expandable list taking 100% of the screen. I want this expandable list to be part of a xml layout.

Comment: 2) The layouts for the generic view and the child view are made programmatically. I would like to load them from XML files.

Comment: Point 2 is answered here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html

Comment: Yes, it is all solved. Thanks!

Comment: then try to move the solution to your question in the answer box. Because, SO is a question-answer site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Point 1 is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999947/android-expandablelistactivity-issue).

Point 2 is answered [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html)